# SQL Como gerar horários para agendamentos com base em alguns critérios?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query, select

Pessoal estou criando um projeto de agendamento de horários para os clientes de uma barbearia.

Os serviços disponibilizados por exemplo são:

```
  name             service_time
______________________________
| Corte de cabelo | 00:30:00 |
| Barba           | 00:15:00 |
| Alisamento      | 00:45:00 |
------------------------------
```

Criei uma função no banco de dados Postgres, para gerar os horários que tenho disponíveis para exibir para o cliente.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION free_hours(start_work TIME, start_launch_time TIME, stop_launch_time TIME, stop_work TIME)
RETURNS TABLE(step INTERVAL, free_hours TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE)
AS $$
  SELECT step::INTERVAL, free_hours FROM
  UNNEST(ARRAY ['15 min', '30 min', '45 min', '60 min']) AS t(step)
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  GENERATE_SERIES(
     '2021-10-20'::date + start_work,
     '2021-10-20'::date + stop_work + INTERVAL '1 day',
     step::INTERVAL
  ) AS free_hours
  WHERE free_hours::TIME NOT BETWEEN start_launch_time AND stop_launch_time
  AND free_hours::TIME >= start_work AND free_hours::TIME <= stop_work
  AND EXTRACT(dow FROM free_hours) <> 0 -- Sunday
  AND free_hours NOT IN (
    SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(
      a.created_at::TIMESTAMP - (step::INTERVAL - '1 min'::INTERVAL)::TIME,
      a.created_at,
      INTERVAL '1 min'
    ) as hours_to_remove
    FROM appointments a
    INNER JOIN services s ON a.service_id = s.id
  )
  AND free_hours NOT IN (
    SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(
      a.created_at,
      a.created_at::TIMESTAMP + s.service_time::TIME - '00:01:00'::TIME,
      INTERVAL '1 min'
    ) as hours_to_remove
    FROM appointments a
    INNER JOIN services s ON a.service_id = s.id
  )
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
```

Essa função, ela gera horários disponíveis para agendamento seguindo algumas regras como:

- Exibi só horários com base no início e fim da jornada de trabalho
- Não lista horários quando o barbeiro está no horário de almoço
- Não lista horários do dia de domingo

E uma outra validação que é feita por essa função, é em cima do horário que o cliente escolheu, ela fica responśavel por gerar 2 novas series, que serve para auxiliar a não correr o risco de aparecer um horário disponível, quando o barbeiro estiver com algum cliente, ou seja, ele garante que o horário escolhido não irá ter interferência de outros horários.

---

Está função está fazendo o que precisa ser feito, mas posso ter cometido um equívoco com ela, nela eu gero a listagem de horários para todos os tempos de serviço que existem: **15min**, **30min**, **45min** e **60min**, esses horários são gerados de forma sequêncial ex: 15min em 15min e assim por diante.

Mas o problema que está me ocorrendo e não estou conseguindo resolver, seria quando acontece o seguinte caso ex:

Marquei um **corte de cabelo** às **09:30**, esse corte tem duração de **30min**, terminando assim às **10:00h**, então nesse horário teria como eu marcar por exemplo um **Alisamento**, que dura **45min**, só que da forma como eu fiz, como os horários no caso de 45min vão de 45min em 45min, o problema que vai acontecer, é que o horário das 10h não estará disponível para eu marcar, ficaria nesse exemplo disponível só o de 10:30

Alguém conseguiria me ajudar? realmente não consegui pensar em outra forma de fazer essa listagem sem aplicar essas regras.

Exemplo de um sistema que faz isso mesmo: https://vuvo181.gendo.app/v2/#/reserve

Link da criação das tabelas e da função, insert e select: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wMK5BP1oXZPdj4Bp1CxWLp/0

Criei um outro exemplo que funciona por meio do preenchimento de slots: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2H3z9pimMie5Ztggx3ZGSV/0

Comment: a lógica ficou meio complexa e não cheguei a analisar mais detalhadamente mas, como a menor unidade de tempo de alocação é 15min, e todos são múltiplos de 15, eu sugeria gerar sempre os tempo de 15min (9:00, 9:15, 9:30, 9:45) e preencher 1 ou mais slots de acordo com o serviço. Por exemplo, um corte marcado às 9:15, iria reservar 9:15 e 9:30 portanto teria 9:00 (só 15m disponível) e 9:45 em diante, dai bastava ver separa o num de slots que o serviço requer tem tempo contínuo disponível (um corte não poderia ser marcado 9:00, apenas 9:45, mas barba poderia)

Comment: então geraria uma tabela diária dessa com esses slots para cada barbeiro, e colocaria no(s) slot(s) o id do agendamento quando esse fosse ocupado, só uma sugestão que talvez simplifique o trabalho :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual obrigado por ter sugerido uma opinião, você fala em gerar uma tabela com esses slots, algo mais ou menos assim? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2UxMk3v7JQ8UuV4KGgGeCT/0

Comment: quase isso, mas só teriar uma tabela com valores "horario, appointmentsId". Imagina o appointment 1 para o barbeiro 10, service 1 (corte, 30min), então a tabela teria esses valores:
horario=09:00, appointmentsId=1 | horario=09:15, appointmentsId=1.. ou seja, o appointment ocupou dois horários, sendo que todos os horários são sempre entre 15 minutos, se o serviço ocupar mais de 15min ocupa mais de um horário (gera mais de uma linha na tabela), não sei se ficou melhor explicado agora

Comment: @RicardoPontual há sim agora entendi seu ponto de vista, irei tentar mudar para essa forma, e ver se vai funcionar certinho, de qualquer forma agradeço pela resposta.

Comment: @RicardoPontual consegui criar com base no que você falou a questão dos slots https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2H3z9pimMie5Ztggx3ZGSV/0 só não estou conseguindo resolver uma coisa, se puder me ajudar, como estou gerando horários de 15 em 15min agora, na hora que o cliente escolher o serviço X de duração de 45min preciso exibir esses horários indo de 45 em 45min, com base nos horários disponíveis no caso, isso se aplica também agora nos horários de 30min, 45min e 60m, você teria como me da um norte para isso, eu tentei mas não consegui fazer algo que funcione.